# What is the difference compiling gcc .c file in comparison to making a .c file into an .o file and linking and assembling?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, vim, compilation

I have just started getting involved with GCC.

Lets say we have a text file written by vim labaled helloworld.c

Why would SWIM (someone who isn't me) compile it with

**gcc helloworld.c** in comparison to **gcc -c helloworld.c** and then **gcc -o helloWorld helloworld.o** ?

Comment: I believe you need to revise the question because "gcc -c helloworld.c" is repeated and you didn't use the linker so far

Comment: If you are combining multiple files into an executable, perhaps compiled from assembler, c, whatever, then compile to object files and then link the object files into an executable. If you only have a single (or couple) of c sources and don't need an object file, then just compile/link in a single step.

Comment: I assume that the first command is not supposed to have the `-c` option? And the only difference between the two ways is that for the first command the object-file generation and linking is done behind the scenes. It's still doing the same thing though.

Comment: Actually SWIY (someone who isn't you) would compile it with `gcc -Wall helloworld.c -o helloworld` so as to get some extra error checking, and an executable with the preferred name.

Comment: Revision done. I didn't know about -Wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one single file, there is no use.
But if you compile a larger project, you may not want to recompile all files, if you only changed one for instance. And thus, gain compile time.

Using intermediate `.o` files lets you only recompile what needs to be recompiled, and link the final binary with all those objects files.

Another usecase is if you want to use a custom link script, for instance to choose the location of your sections or code. Then you need to get the actual code from `.o` files.

Comment: In practice, for a project with several `.c` source files, you want to use a builder like `make`. See [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/273582/40065) for why !

Answer (score 1):

There are some phases in compiler process:

Preprocessing -> Compiling -> Assembling -> Linking.

Phases:

- Preprocessing : include some test from your .h files into your .c files and create a preprocessed source code.
- Compiling : create assembler code from your preprocessed code.
- Assembling : create object modules from your assembler code.
- Linking : create executable files from your object modules.

When you use `gcc [options]`:

If you use:

- `gcc -E` Stops after preprocessing phase and gives you preprocessed code.
- `gcc -S` Stops after Compiling phase and gives you assembler code.
- `gcc -c` Stops after Assembling phase and gives you a object module.

`gcc -o` gives you a executable file with included name, by default gives you `a.out`

[man gcc HERE](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)