# MySQL: Library not loaded from C program

Tags: mysql, sql, c, macos

I'd like to test the very simple C API connection with my MySQL server. And I'm using it on mac. So Here are the codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

exit(0);
}
```

I use gcc to compile it

```
gcc -c `mysql_config --cflags` main.c
```

It succeeds. But when I tried to run it

```
./main.o
```

The error is like this

```
-bash: ./main.o: Permission denied
```

I can log in to the MySQL by anonymous and run select version():

```
shell>mysql
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.6.25    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks to Sean, there is a mistake in my compilation. It supposes to be

```
gcc -o main `mysql_config --cflags` main.c `mysql_config --libs`
```

After that when I run ./main
I get another error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Thanks everyone!

I've solved this by adding the path of libmysqlclient.dylib to the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
Here is the command for someone may need it.

```
 export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

Comment: I'm sure there are a number of questions on `gcc`, `-c` and `.o` files, but [this might be of interest](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28644317/372643), or [this (unfortunately closed)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27031199/372643).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-c` argument to `gcc` means:

> Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.

Which means you are not producing a valid executable. You need an additional step:

```
gcc -c `mysql_config --cflags` main.c
gcc -o main main.o `mysql_config --libs`
```

This can also be combined into a single line:

```
gcc -o main `mysql_config --cflags` main.c `mysql_config --libs`
```

Then you should be able to run `./main`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forget to run the second compilation line so I get the access denied error. But after I add that, and running ./main, I have another error.    dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib. Maybe you also have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation ststement looks wrong.

```
 gcc -c `mysql_config --cflags` main.c
```

does not produce an executable binary. `-c` option is used to produce the object file, not an executable. It stops after compilation, linking is not done.

Rather, to generate the binary, you should write

```
gcc main.c -o outfile <any other oprions>
```

where the `-o <file>` is used to place the output (binary) to `<file>`and run the `outfile` like

```
./outfile
```